# By implementing a follower & feed system for a social media platform allowing users to follow and unfollow others, I experience performance issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a social media platform that needs to allow users to follow each other and see a feed of posts from the users they follow.
I need to implement a follower system that allows users to follow and unfollow other users, and a feed system that displays posts from followed users.

I've built these code snippets; however, I experience

performance issues if there are a large number of followers or if the system is being heavily used.

it becomes difficult to implement pagination or filtering features.

Can you propose me some other alternatives for heavy usage and many numbers of followers?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def follow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def unfollow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.unfollow(@user)
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :follows, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :follows
  has_many :followings, class_name: 'Follow', foreign_key: 'follower_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :following_users, through: :followings, source: :user

  def follow(user)
    return if self == user
    follows.create(user_id: user.id)
  end

  def unfollow(user)
    follows.where(user_id: user.id).destroy_all
  end

  def feed
    following_users.includes(:posts).map(&:posts).flatten.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
  end
end

class Follow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = current_user.feed
  end
end
```

Comment: `feed` could be `Post.where(user_id: following_users).order(created_at: :desc)` which will be much more efficient.

Comment: Hi, could be good if you can add some metrics (what is "long", and with how many data in your database?, and under which load ?)

Comment: You could limit the number of posts being pulled in a single query. For eg, show 50 posts first and use the 50th post's id to fetch the next 50.